# how would i find the length? i have 8 tubes and 11 nodes

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

So i have 11 tubes and 8 nodes.
The lenght is the distance from node 1 to node 2.
[image: Have a look at this picture for more information]

```
8 //nodes
11 //tubes
0 0 -50 //node_x, node_y, flow
1000 0 -50 //node_x, node_y, flow
2000 0 0 //node_x, node_y, flow
0 500 0 //node_x, node_y, flow
500 500 0 //node_x, node_y, flow  // NODES
0 1000 -50 //node_x, node_y, flow
1000 1000 0 //node_x, node_y, flow
2000 1000 150 //node_x, node_y, flow
1 2 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
2 3 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
1 4 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
4 5 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
2 5 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
2 8 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter // TUBES
3 8 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
4 6 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
6 7 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
5 7 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
7 8 0.5 //Node_1, Node_2, Diameter
```

As seen the text file above we have 8 data for nodes with node x,y,flow values and 11 data for tubes with its node 1,2 id and diameter.

which means the first data of tube which is id 1 and id 2 = to 0 0 -50 and 1000 0 -50 so the length is 1000. As shown in picture we need the x value here so x is returned in the c++.

**My code right now is hard coded which is like this:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    //1
    if (node1_[i].id() == 0 && node2_[i].id() == 1)
    {
        return node2_->x();
    }
    //2
    if (node1_[i].id() == 1 && node2_[i].id() == 2)
    {
        return node1_->x();
    }
    //3
    if (node1_[i].id() == 0 && node2_[i].id() == 3)
    {
        return node2_->y();
    }
    //4
    if (node1_[i].id() == 3 && node2_[i].id() == 4)
    {
        return node2_->x();
    }
    //5
    if (node1_[i].id() == 1 && node2_[i].id() == 4)
    {
        return std::sqrt((node2_->x()) * (node2_->x()) + (node2_->y()) * (node2_->y()));
    }
    //6
    if (node1_[i].id() == 1 && node2_[i].id() == 7)
    {
        return std::sqrt((node1_->x()) * (node1_->x()) + (node2_->y()) * (node2_->y()));
    }
    //7
    if (node1_[i].id() == 2 && node2_[i].id() == 7)
    {
        return node2_->y();
    }
    //8
    if (node1_[i].id() == 3 && node2_[i].id() == 5)
    {
        return node1_->y();
    }
    //9
    if (node1_[i].id() == 5 && node2_[i].id() == 6)
    {
        return node2_->x();
    }
    //10
    if (node1_[i].id() == 4 && node2_[i].id() == 6)
    {
        return std::sqrt((node1_->x()) * (node1_->y()) + (node1_->x()) * (node1_->y()));
    }
    //11
    if (node1_[i].id() == 6 && node2_[i].id() == 7)
    {
        return node1_->x();
    }
}
```

**How can i remove the manually written ids and make it data driven so it knows which id to pick itself**

```
length[0] = 1000
length[1] = 1000
length[2] = 500
length[3] = 500
length[4] = 707.107
length[5] = 1414.21
length[6] = 1000
length[7] = 500
length[8] = 1000
length[9] = 707.107
length[10] = 1000
```

these are values which i am getting which are correct. **but i would like to change the way i am doing it. change the hard coded method to a data driven way.**

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the `11` make it a variable to read in at the beginning. For the Tubes do the same.

Comment: Instead of naming the variable in the `for` loop `i`, give it the name `id` and use that inside the code block.

Comment: Please do not link to external sites. Provide all the necessary information in the question.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk can you elaborate a little bit more. i am trying to do what u are telling what i am not able to get the same results. is it possible if you could write some pseudo code for me.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. How come you can need to access `node2_[i].id()` and can then do `node2_->x()`? Shouldn't this be `node2_[i].x()`? What is the "id". Need WAY more info here.

Comment: @JHBonarius: That is entirely legal C++. It's directly inherited from C. You should be able to figure this out; `node2_` is a pointer. Hence `node2->` is equivalent to `node2_[0].`

Comment: @MSalters yes, I know. I meant to point out if it's a typo. Does the OP know he's accessing idx 0? (p.s. it's only correct for C-style arrays. If they were std::vectors it wouldn't be.)

Comment: To "generalize" your calculations you need a "generalized"  function which calculates based on the amount of nodes connected to a tube.

Answer (score 0):

To "generalize" your calculations you need a "generalized"  function which calculates based on the amount of nodes connected to a tube.
This You have to find yourself.

After reading in the data, what is needed can be calculated.
Here is an idea for reading the data:

- Define class'es for `Tube`'s and `Node`'s.
- Use a `std::vector` to contain them (`std::vector<Tube> tubes;` and `std::vector<Node> nodes;`
- `tubes` should be contained inside the `Node` class
- Read in all the tubes and nodes.
- While reading tubes assign the lower numbered node number as the location of the tube
- loop over the nodes and calculate using it's tubes using the generalized function

Comment: Nodes are shared between tubes, not contained in them. And it's really easier to model it the other way around, as each tube has exactly two node endpoints, but other way around varies between 2 and 4 tubes per node.

Comment: @MSalters After some though, you're right. I got my tubes and nodes mixed.